# Cut a hole in a door?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `<div>` which has a background image of wood repeating.

I now want to cut a hole in this for a window. Is there any way to do this in HTML and CSS? Javascript welcome.

See this example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UWyvz/)

Comment: Instead of "cutting a hole" in the div, depending on your needs you can put the background into the window above the door div.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I could use a background image to simulate a transparency, I cannot use canvas as the door is 3D and moves around

Comment: I'd recommend using the `<svg>` method :) see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple - draw the door using paths in the `<svg>` element.

```
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg-door">
    <defs>
         <pattern id="wood" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1024" height="768">
             <image xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/Ljug3pp.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="1024" height="768" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="
        M0,0 225,0 225,300 0,300 z
        M165,10, 215,10 215,80 165,80 z
    " fill="url(#wood)" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
</svg>
```

The CSS:

```
#svg-door {
   background-image: url(http://pcdn.500px.net/15548893/7f3b7c411716b1fb29c5cffb3efcf8ce33eacd76/15.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

The advantage of this method is that your background can be anything, and the window is a genuine window (see-through).

I have precalculated the paths for you, and you can find the new door in the fork that I have created from your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/qS4G7/

[Edit] For completeness sake, I have also used a wooden texture as the background image for the svg path.

Comment: This looks really good! How do you calculate the paths? Can the paths be dynamically created if I were to re-position the window?

Comment: Simple mathematics :) 

The outer rectangle has the following paths (in x,y coordinates) - 0,0 -> 225,0 -> 225,300 -> 0,300.

The inner rectangle has the following paths (calculated from your specifications in the original fiddle) - 165,10 -> 215,10 -> 215,80 -> 165,80.

I have added the 100px padding just to move the svg element from the border, so you can better visualize the real "transparentness" of the window.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/UWyvz/3/

I basically used some wood and created a window pane.

Nah, I replicated the `window`, but called it `windowpane`, then set the window pane's `z-index` to be lower than that of the `window`'s and set the `background-color` of `windowpane` to white.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I would need a more realistic looking at the moment the example still doesn't look transparent

Comment: Just lower the opacity of the `window` class? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/UWyvz/6/

Comment: @mattytommo - the window is not double glazed and left wide open to burglars. Best get batman on this!

Comment: @DarrenDavies Hahaha you're right, you need a DC superhero. How about Green Lantern? :D

Comment: @mattytommo - superman all the way ;)

Comment: @DarrenDavies We already have a superman, that's Paul aka SuperFlem!

Comment: @CR41G14 Out of interest, why did you mark me as the answer and then un-mark it? :)

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit of an "ugly fix", but it works: using the `border-property` to simulate a door (the element is actually the window).

**HTML**

```
<div class="door"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-image:url("http://wallpapers.free-review.net/wallpapers/42/Sun_in_white_cloud.jpg");
}
.door {
    height:70px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4);
    border-left: 175px solid orange;
    border-top: 10px solid orange;
    border-right: 10px solid orange;
    border-bottom: 230px solid orange;
    border-image:url("http://roundsquarewoodworking.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/wood-texture-background.jpg") 25% repeat;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X8Zc5/1/).

**EDIT**

Updated the code to see the "see-through" effect. The borders aren't perfect, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is an alternative as it does mimic the cut out better than the other suggestions

Comment: This is a rather ingenious solution - never thought of it, heh.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use canvas html5. http://www.html5canvastutorials.com

Comment: Do you have any examples of how this can be achieved using canvas? As my door is not static I am unsure if this can be an option